# Java RMI - NoSuchObjectException: no such object in Table (only via HTTP Proxy!)

Tags: java, exception, rmi, http-proxy

got a Problem with my RMI Test...

Server:

```
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(non-default-port);
obj = new HelloImpl(); 
Naming.rebind("//ip-of-server/HelloServer", obj);
```

Client:

```
RMISocketFactory.setSocketFactory(new sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIHttpToCGISocketFactory());

obj = (Hello) LocateRegistry.getRegistry("ip of server", non-default-port).lookup( "HelloServer");

obj.sayHello("test");
```

All objects are static in the class..

But i get a "java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table"-Exception all the time.. 
This only happens, if i use the HTTP Tunneling via

```
RMISocketFactory.setSocketFactory(new sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIHttpToCGISocketFactory());
```

If i try it without the HTTP Tunneling (from a other PC in the normal web), it works fine!

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You will be getting this from the `sayHello()` rather than the `lookup()`. The meaning of the exception is that the stub is 'stale', i.e. the remote object has been unexported, which probably means it has been DGC'd as well. You should try the following, in this order, one at a time:

1. Keep a static reference to the value returned by `createRegistry()`.

   This should be sufficient by itself, but if it isn't:
2. Keep a static reference to the remote object itself, and no I do not mean its stub. In this case, `obj`.

I can't explain why it happens via HTTP tunnelling only, but you should do (1) in all cases anyway, so really it is a bug waiting to happen via any means.

Comment: thanks for your reply!
Declared both already static in my Client:
static Registry reg; 
static Hello obj;
but this didnt worked..

Comment: `createRegistry()` is called by the server, not the client. I am referring to the server.

Comment: Correct.. Still the same error.. all is static but nothing changed

Comment: Not in the code you posted. You are throwing away the result of `createRegistry()`, not storing it anywhere, let alone in a static variable.

Comment: Yea i changed it after you told me this.. But it doesnt work even if i store the return value from createRegistry() in a static class variable

Comment: Please edit your question to show your current server code.